# UIToolbar leaves white rectangle when hidden

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app has 5 tabs with navigation controllers in each.

In one of my tabs I use the navigation controllers default toolbar.

And when my web view loads I want to hide it.

But when I do it leaves a white rectangle right above the tab bar.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks!!

```
- (void)loadView
{
CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:screenFrame];

[wv setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[wv setDelegate:self];

[self setView:wv];
[wv release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you hide the navigationBar you have to resize the UIWebView. 
ex:

```
myWebView.frame = [self.view.frame];
```

Comment: I figured it out from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563956/iphone-cgaffinetransformrotatepi-2-statusbarhiddenyes-presentmodalviewc